# I am currently writing a stock control system and getting a 105 error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

I am writing a stock control system and when coding the last thing, I got a 105 error. I was just wondering if anyone had any ideas of what is wrong.

```
closefile(ContractOrdersfile);
closefile(ContractFile);

assignfile(ContractPriceListFile, 'Contract Price List.txt');
rewrite(ContractPriceListFile);
reset(ContractFile);

while not eof(ContractFile) do
begin
    read(ContractFile, Contract);
      if Contract.Flag = true then
       begin
        Writeln(Contract.Contract_Name + '  ' + inttostr(Contract.Contract_ID) + '  ' +     CurrtoStr(Contract.Search_Price));
        Contract.Search_Price := StrtoCurr('0.00');
        Seek(ContractFile, (Filepos(ContractFile)-1));
        write(ContractFile, Contract);
       end;
end;

ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', PChar('notepad'), PChar('Contract Price List.txt'), nil,    SW_SHOW);
closefile(ContractFile);
closefile(ContractPriceListFile);enter code here
```

Comment: assignfile etc. are dinosaur methods - consider using for example TStringList instead

Comment: Please don't force notepad on the poor user. Use the open verb on the text file and respect the user's preferences.

Comment: This is supposed to open the text file, it activates when a button is pressed

Comment: Indeed. But please let the user decide what text editor they like. Any program that forces me to use Notepad is immediately uninstalled. `ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'Contract Price List.txt', nil, nil, SW_SHOW)`

Comment: I've reverted your edit. It's improper to remove the entire content of the question after you've started receiving answers;  it invalidates the answers (they no longer match the question), and it wastes the time (and sometimes the reputation) of people who have made the effort to assist you. If you don't want to accept the answer that solved your problem, that's fine, but leave the information to help future users of this site that may have a similar problem and need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I/O Error 105 is "File not open for output". It's usually caused by failing to set the appropriate [FileMode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.FileMode) after opening the file, or by using Write or WriteLn from a non-console application.

It's most likely caused by the `WriteLn` inside the `if` block that writes contract info. It appears to be going to the console (no file is specified as the first argument). You should probably provide a file as the first argument, or make sure you're running a console application.

Comment: the reset(ContractFile) needs to be there as it opens the file, without it a 103 error would appear, and it is also a different file to the one that is stored into the text file

Comment: Yeah, I see that, along with the mixed writes to file and the console. The poster needs to use the debugger to figure out which line is causing the error in order to track it down.

Comment: Just tested it, without the writeln... It works fine (apart from not doing what it needs to)

Comment: Well, if it works fine without the WriteLn, you've identified the problem that's causing the 105 error, which relates back to the first paragraph here, I'd suspect - WriteLn in a non-console app?

Comment: YES, as it was writing to a text file, I had to specify what file it was writing to before adding the variables that were being added. Thanks!